# How can I use a trait implementation from another crate in the original crate?

Tags: rust, traits, workspace, rust-crates

I have a Rust project which divided among several crates in a workspace. One of these crates is a test crate which holds utilities for use in unit and integration tests within the other crates.

In one crate I define a trait that is implemented by a struct in the test crate. However, when I try to use the struct from the test crate in the original crate which defined the trait, I encounter errors when trying to use the trait's member functions.

Here is a short example:

In the `project-trait` crate:

```rust
trait Trait {
    fn do_something(&self)
}
```

In the `project-test` crate:

```rust
use project_trait::Trait;

pub struct TestObject;

impl Trait for TestObject {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Finally, back in the `project-trait` crate:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use crate::Trait;
    use project_test::TestObject;

    #[test]
    fn use_test_object() {
        let object = TestObject;
        object.do_something();
    }
}
```

When running `cargo test` in the `project-trait` crate, I get error E0599 which says I should import `project_trait::Trait` to use the `do_something` method. It seems Rust doesn't see that `crate::Trait` and `project_trait::Trait` are the same trait.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can't be cycles in the crate dependency graph. Therefore, whatever you've actually done in your project configuration, it can't be that the `#[cfg(test)]` code that is depending on `project-test` is using the same `crate::Trait` as what `project-test` sees as `project_trait::Trait`.

You have probably done something that causes some of the code to be compiled as part of a different crate (such as misuse of `mod` so as to compile the same source file in two crates). The result of this is that you have two different traits that happen to both be named `Trait`. Thus, you get an error because the one that `TestObject` implements is not the same as the one you have imported.

(In order to get a more precise explanation of what's going wrong, you'll need to provide a more complete example — preferably reproducible, i.e. "if I copy  these files into a local folder they will be sufficient to demonstrate the problem".)

In general, whatever code is needed to run `project-trait`'s tests must be part of the `project-trait` crate or its dependencies — you can't split out test helpers into an independent library crate.

Comment: I have the same issue, in the rust book they explain how to use the `add` function from the `tests/integration_test.rs` which works like `adder::add_two(2)`. But how about a member function like `do_something()` in this example?? Please tell us the correct answer! It's already `pub` by default.

Comment: @DrumM I can't tell from your description what the problem is, and comments are not a good place to ask questions. Please **post a separate question** and include all the code for an example project that demonstrates the problem. Don't worry, I'll see it as long as it's tagged [tag:rust].